# Download with QNetworkAccessManager / QNetworkReply using readyRead() eats my RAM

Tags: qt, qml, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply, qnetworkrequest

I'm having the following setup and scenario:

- QT/QML-application running, which can be triggered to download a 20MB file to `/tmp/IMAGE` (using `QNetworkManager()`, `QNetworkReply()`, `readyRead()`)
- `/tmp` is a ramdisk - having 40+MB of available space (while the QT/QML-application is running)
- I can easily `wget` the 20MB file to `/tmp/IMAGE` while the QT/QML-application is running

**however** when trying to download the file via the QT/QML-application (using `QNetworkManager()`, `QNetworkReply()` and the `readyRead()`-signal, the qt/qml-application gets killed by the out-of-memory killer even before half the file is actually downloaded (according to `downloadProgress()` and size of `/tmp/IMAGE`).

As far as I understood, `readyRead()` is especially designed for partially downloading chunks, writing it to disk, clearing its used RAM and downloading and writing the next chunk.

However that method seems to massively consume more RAM, than e.g. using `wget` - after having 10MB of the file downloaded, the Qt/QML-application has a huge memory footprint which I can't explain.

What I'm basically doing, it connecting the `readyRead()` with my slot named `partialDownloadFinished()` which only does: `file->write(reply->readAll());`

I also checked whether the chunk size might be or might get to large via `bytesAvailable()`, however that also doen't seem to be the case.

My next guess was that data is downloaded faster than being written to (ram)disk, however that also doesn't seem to be the case.

So I'm stuck. Anybody having any clue or hint on this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing any code, but `QNetworkReply::readAll()` is going to attempt to download the entire file into RAM. Try using the `read()` method instead and download the file in small chunks.

Comment: Not really, `readAll` returns all the *available* data. Can you see any progress while downloading? Have you tried checking where your app is using memory while downloading? Have you tried throttling down via `QNetworkReply::setReadBufferSize`?